# Probability of $5$ persons getting their exact car key

Tags: probability, derangements

> $5$ persons play with their car keys such that
> after the game none leaves with his own key and everybody has exactly one key.
> It is not possible for all five of them to meet at one place again. If the probability that they
> can still have their right key back assuming each one of them meets one or more
> friends at most once is $P$, then  $P$ equals

We know that derangement of $n$ distinct object in $n$ places as

$\displaystyle n!\bigg(1-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{5!}-\cdots \bigg)$

So derangement of $5$ distinct object

in $5$ places as

(All $5$ persons not getting its eaxct key)

$\displaystyle n!\bigg(1-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{5!} \bigg)=44$

And arrangement of $5$ distinct

object in $5$ places is $5!=120$

So probability in which all persons not getting its exact key

$\displaystyle \frac{44}{120}=\frac{11}{30}$

And probability of at least one person getting its exact key

$\displaystyle =1-\frac{11}{30}=\frac{19}{30}$

But here I did not know how I find probability $P$

Please have a look

I have got that question from

https://brainly.in/question/42410041

Comment: You have not specified what happens when friends meet and how the order of meeting is chosen.  Presumably when they meet they have the option to exchange the keys they have.  Can one give their key to the other without receiving one?  We need more details.  The formatting at the start takes a huge amount of space.  Why not just have text?

Comment: @Ross Millikan I have attached link of that problem above

Comment: @PritiBisht please include all necessary details in the text body and avoid the usage of external links.